# Why Youtube API v3 quota is wrong?

Tags: java, youtube-api, quota, discord-jda

I'm currently coding a Discord Bot, using Discord-JDA, that's notices me when my, or friends, Twitch link is used on a YouTube video's description (Best Of Twitch mainly).

I'm calling this API route five times (5 Twitch links)

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet
```

Because of false positive and video description being truncate with the previous call, I have to iterate on each results calling this one, for a total of around 60 vids.

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet
```

According to [quota cost caculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost#videos). That should cost me around 5x100 + 60x1 = 560 but I get a cost of 1.000

[image: Quota Screenshot]

Is there any known issue or if google provides a way to see calling logs.

Comment: how many times did you try it on the same minute?

Comment: Only one time, that's why I find it strange

Comment: There are no call logs and the image you are posting from google cloud console is a estimate it is not accurate in any realm of reality.  Nor is it realtime.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for the response, seems strange that they only provide an estimate tho. I guess I'll only request each 8h so that I won't exceed quota :)

Comment: Its a free api you get what you pay for.  if you go over the quota you will know you will get a quota exceeded error.